# ESP32-C3 Picoclick C3 missing component

Tags: antenna, esp32, wifi, bluetooth-low-energy, open-source

I'm putting together a small PCB.

It's based on the open source Picoclick-C3 by the fantastic maker MoeKoe:

https://makermoekoe.gitbook.io/picoclick-c3/hardware

In the part of the circuit for the wifi / BLE antenna, there's an unlabelled capacitor.

[image: antenna part of the circuit]

Source: https://github.com/makermoekoe/Picoclick-C3/blob/main/pcb/Picoclick_C3/picoclick_c3_v1.1.pdf

The antenna is a SLDA31-3R400G-S1TF, and unfortunately, the data sheet from LCSC doesn't have an 'typical use' circuit, and the EAGLE board file is missing the value too, so I'm stuck as to how to choose the value for this capacitor.

What value should it have, and how would you find out?

Alternatively, how should a general antenna for an ESP32-C3 circuit be designed?

Comment: Why is capacitor C18 measured in Henrys? Surely that should be 1 nF?

Comment: Right?? I assumed that it was an inductor with the wrong label / wrong symbol.

Comment: Ask the person who designed this. The filter is usually a CLC filter, not CCL. But the chip antenna may require it. The caps in the schematic are just placeholders for antenna tuning components. One of the components might really need to be an inductor.

Comment: I did indeed email moekoe first, but he has a big following, lots of newbies via his (great) YouTube channel must reach out to him, so I don't expect him to reply to every little email. Putting a wifi antenna on a PCB must be a common thing that the community knows how to do, hoping someone can give me an example so I can charge on.

Comment: @legoblocks Designing a wifi antenna for any device requires in-depth knowledge on RF circuits, which is comparable with black magic for the uninitiated. These components are used to tune/match the RF output to the antenna, and the characteristics of the PCB must also be taken into account. If you altered the PCB layout regarding the RF section in any way, the component values are not valid any more. Same applies if you did not use the exact same PCB material with same properties and layer stack-up.

Comment: For hobby project, you can leave it as "blank" like what moekoe did, because to be honest, unless the product has gone through the certification and antenna matching during the design, many of the electronic designers have no idea what the value should be. Many RF design have those capacitor value as "blank" or having the capacitor unpopulated because they don't know what value should be until the PCB has gone through the antenna matching calibration in a RF measurement chamber.

Comment: Having said that, as a hobbyist, you need to do some controlled impedance traces during your PCB design and ask for impedance matching  and particular material/process when you order your PCB, I would suggest that you watch this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fteCxn5XXA) as the beginning.

Comment: Great answer, thankyou @hcheung